# Trying to write JSON data to a txt file using Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

My project is to take input from the user and write it to the end of a text file in JSON format using ajax and php. Problem is that the php only writes the time and date to the end of the file and nothing else. I took the example from a previous post and modified it here for my purposes. Here's the html
movie.html:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script src="movie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>
            <center>
                <input id="box" type="textbox"name="box" value="Enter Movie:"/>
                <input id="add" type="button" value="Submit" onClick="addStuff();" /></center>
        </h1>
        <div id="status" ></div>

        <h2>MOVIE NAME:</h2>

        <ul id="list" name="list">
            </ul>
        <div id="status"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the movie.js file which sends the data via Ajax:

```
function addStuff(){
var movie_name_entered = document.getElementById("box").value;
var movieList = document.getElementById("list");

var hr= new XMLHttpRequest();
var url= "movie.php";
hr.open("POST",url,true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Context-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var param = "film=" + movie_name_entered;
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", param.length);
hr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
hr.onreadystatechange= function(){
    if(hr.readyState==4 && hr.status==200){
        var return_data=hr.responseText;
        console.log(hr.responseText);
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=return_data;
    }
}
hr.send(param);
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

Here's the php (btw, I console.logged the data being sent to the php and it is correct):

```
<?php
if($_POST){
$data = $_POST["film"];
$file ='movie.txt';
$fp = fopen($file, "a");
$encoded = json_encode($data);
fwrite($fp, $encoded);
fclose($fp);    
return $encoded;}
?>
```

As mentioned above, the code only writes the time and date to the text file and nothing more no matter what I do. I tested the data being sent and it's valid $_POST data. I'm not sure how else to proceed. Any helop would be appreciated. Thx!

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The text file is called movie.txt and is referenced in the php file. it's in the same directory as the other 3 files and is the only file that is being updated by the php. I think the time/date stamp may be an indication of the moment the exchange took place rather than the actual data.

Comment: OK, so it turns out that whenever I tested the app I had the text file open on my desktop and I Ctl+f5 to refresh it. That action pasted the date/time into the empty (seemingly) text file. I tried the code listed below and did the same and I got the same result. Then I tried the code below and closed the text file and re-opened it and voila, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code in movie.js

```
function addStuff() {
    var movie_name_entered = document.getElementById("box").value;
    var movieList = document.getElementById("list");

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "movie.php";
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var param = "film=" + movie_name_entered;
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", param.length);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            console.log(hr.responseText);
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(param);
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

Please change your php code to below

```
if ($_POST) {
    $data    = $_POST["film"];
    $file    = 'movie.txt';
    $fp      = fopen($file, "a+");
    $encoded = json_encode($data);
    fwrite($fp, $encoded);
    fclose($fp);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. It works! Well, it kinda works. It does write to the file the correct data, however, it does not get the data again once it's written and pull it back into the page. I suspect I'll have to write a separate function to do that. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

you are getting a empty `$_POST` variable so your php code is never gets executed. you have a mistake in your code :

```
hr.setRequestHeader("Context-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

it should be `Content-type` , replace `x` with `c` :D